# React-router 2.0: programmatically change route (URL not updated)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having some trouble with programmatically routing with react-router 2.0

The docs say to use

```
this.context.router.push('/test');
```

This is navigating correctly, but the URL on my browser stays the same and does not update even though the components from the other page (/test) have rendered and the route change was successful.

How can I get the URL to update?

Comment: It is hard to answer accurately without a test case. Can you reproduce this in a gist and link it here?

Answer (score 10):

`this.props.history.push('/some/path');` been deprecated.

We should now use the following:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
```

Then, wherever you want to navigate - somewhere in your code - do:

```
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

This is how I configured my `routes.jsx` file that handles my routing mechanism:

```
//Require react.
import React from "react";
//Require routing variables.
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";
//Example components.
import MainComponent from "../containers/main.js";
import HomeComponent from "../containers/home.js";

var Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={MainComponent}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomeComponent} />
            <Route path="/example" component={ExampleComponent} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

I'm using webpack. In webpack, I also have this:

```
... bla ... bla... bla ...
module: {

},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
},
plugins: [

]
... bla ... bla... bla ...
```

---

UPDATE 04-Jan-2018:

[Disclaimer: I'm now using TypeScript instead of ES6]

This is how I get things done right now with `react` `^15.6.1` & `react-dom` `^15.6.1`

`index.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Routes from "./configuration/routes";
ReactDOM.render(
  Routes,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

`routes.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter  } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from "../containers/App";

let Routes: any = (
    // <BrowserRouter>
    //     <App someDefaultValue/>
    // </BrowserRouter>

    // HashRouter adds the # in front of our paths :) - check the browser's URL to see.
    <HashRouter>
        <App someDefaultValue/>
    </HashRouter>
);
export default Routes;
```

`App.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from "../components/header-component/header";
import Main from "../components/main-component/main";
import Footer from "../components/footer-component/footer";

interface IComponentProps { someDefaultValue: boolean; }
interface IComponentState { loading: boolean; }

class App extends React.Component<IComponentProps, IComponentState> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            loading: true
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state;
        if(loading) {
            //Render something or something else..
        }

        return (
            <div className="app-container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={Header}/>
                </Switch>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={Main}/>
                </Switch>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={Footer}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

You can then use something like this to place navigation on menu items when clicked (or whatever...)
`menu.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to='/home'>
                    <div>Home</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/about'>
                    <div>About</div>
                </Link>
            </div>);
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

To navigate 'programically':

```
this.props.history.push('/wherever');
```

The reason I am using `HashRouter`, is because I noticed with `BrowserRouter` that it breaks when people saved 'bookmarks' etc. HashRouter allows my users to seamlessly navigate my site :)

If I need to show how `BrowserRouter` works, I can - just ask - it's nearly the same - but you will see that it only behaves when you navigate within the website. When you navigate from the outside, that's when the errors starts to happen.

Oh, yeah, almost forgot - I did not really test this, but I assume we still need

```
devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }
```

in our `webpack.config.js`? Wouldn't know :)... but it's there in mine right now...

Comment: this worked for me however It's worth mentioning to use the historyAPI you use in your router, I was using `hashHistory`

Comment: I am getting this error  'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'. Any Suggestions?

Comment: LOL, react has, once again, changed since the day this was posted :). I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) may be what you're looking for it says to use

```
this.props.history.push('/some/path');
```

when inside of a component

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but according to the docs that is v1 https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#navigating-in-route-components

Comment: This works for me!!  "react": "15.3.2","react-dom": "15.3.2","react-router": "2.6.0".

Comment: this.props.history.push is now deprecated. Use browserHistory.push instead.

Comment: this is deprecated